# height and width values for css in chrome are too small. Or is the width too large?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-rendering, webpage-rendering

I have a web site page that doesn't seem to be rendering properly for chrome in safari.

It appears it is rendering the width of the screen with twice as many pixels as other browsers. I suspect it may be the initial viewport settings, which work in all other browsers for windows and apple, except for the version of chrome on mac.

I tried removing the viewport setting but that doesn't seem to work. I am using the latest version of Chrome, and if I have a window open in safari beside chrome you can see that chrome is rendering the screen as twice as wide, even though it takes up the same width.

Oops. I can't post an image, but you can see it here: http://straathof.acadnet.ca/test_chrome.jpg

If you would like to test it, you can visit the page here: http://straathof.acadnet.ca/reblend55

Any help for tracking down this problem would be appreciated. I have no idea where to look.

Comment: That page has over 100 HTML errors -- always a contributor to "browser diversity".  Try cleaning up the code so that it validates.  With luck that will fix, or shed light upon, the problem.

Comment: I just opened your site in chrome but I'm not seeing the page rendered per the screenshot you have attached. Have you tried disabling any extensions you have running in chrome that could be interfering?

Comment: weird. I had it down tozero html errors a few versions ago. time to regroup.

Answer (score 0):

control-0 removed any zooms that had been added to the web page, which allowed it to render properly at the correct width. Apparently some months ago I zoomed in on something and, even though Chrome was removed reinstalled and reset, not to mention quit and restarted a whole lot of times, it still remembered that errant zoom value.

annoying, but answered with someone elses suggestion.